# Library Program - Assigning & checking out books

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I'm supposed to create a library program in java that allows you to create patrons and check out a maximum of 3 books. I'm really beginner at java so I apologize that my code is all over the place and may not make sense.

Below is the library class that I attempted(i also have a separate Patron, Book and Book Interface class)
My main concerns:

- I have 2 ArrayLists, one for a list of inputed Users and another for a list of inputed Books. However how would i be able to assign certain checked out books to a certain user & make sure they borrow no more than 3?
- I put a lot of the code in the main method but i end up having a lot of problems with static and non static stuff
- How would I be able to create status' for each book? for example if "great expectations" is checked out, how can assign "borrowed" to it and make sure no one else can borrow it?

The program runs so far but its lacking depth because I'm lost as to how to check out/in books under a certain specified patron.

SORRY again for all the inconsistencies in my code and i really really appreciate the help!

```js
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Collections; 
public class Library 
{


 static ArrayList <Patron> UserList = new ArrayList<Patron>();
 static ArrayList <String> BookList = new ArrayList <String> (); 
 
 public static String status;
 public static String borrower; 
 public static String borrowDate; 
 public static String returnDate; 
 public String status1 = "Available";
 public String status2 = "Borrowed";
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int choice = 0;
  System.out.println("********************Welcome to the Public Library!********************");
  System.out.println("              Please Select From The Following Options:               ");
  System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
  
  while(choice != 9)
  {
   System.out.println("1: Add new patron");
   System.out.println("2: Add new book");
   System.out.println("3: Edit patron");
   System.out.println("4: Edit book");
   System.out.println("5: Display all patrons");
   System.out.println("6: Display all books");
   System.out.println("7: Check out book");
   System.out.println("8: Check in book");
   System.out.println("9: Search book");
   System.out.println("10: Search Patron");
   System.out.println("9: Exit");
   choice = input.nextInt();

   
  switch(choice)
  {
  case 1: //Add new patron
   System.out.print("Enter patron first name: ");
   String firstName = input.next(); //read name from input
   System.out.print("Enter patron last name: ");
   String lastName = input.next(); 

   UserList.add(new Patron(firstName, lastName)); //add name to list
   System.out.println("-----You have successfully added a new patron!-----");
   break; 
       
  case 2: //Add new book
   System.out.print("Enter book title: ");
   String title1 = input.next();
    
   Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter book author: ");
   String author1 = input.next(); 

   Book book1 = new Book(title1);    
   BookList.add(title1);
   FullBookList.add(fullBook);
   System.out.println("-----You have successfully added a new book!-----");
   
   status = "available";
   borrowDate = "none";
   returnDate = "none";
   borrower = "none";
   
   break; 
   
  case 3: //Edit patron name
   System.out.println("Enter original patron name: ");
   String originalName = input.next(); 
   System.out.println("Enter edited patron name: ");
   String editedName = input.next(); 
   //Collections.replaceAll(UserList, originalName, editedName);
   if(UserList.contains(originalName))
   {
    
   }
    
  case 4: //edit book
   
   
  case 5: //display all patrons 
    System.out.println(UserList); 
    break; 
    
  case 6: //display all books 
    System.out.println(BookList); 
    break; 
    
  case 7: //check out a book
    Patron.CheckOutBook(); 
    break; 
  case 8: //check in a book
    Patron.CheckInBook(); 
    break; 
    
   
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Patron 
{
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 private String first; 
 private String last; 
 int bookCount = 0; //amount books user has in pocket
 int books = 0;
 
 
 //constructor to "add new patron" by entering their name. 
 public Patron(String f, String l)
 {
  first = f; 
  last = l; 
 }
 
 public String toString()
 {
  return first + " " + last; 
 }
 
 public String getName() 
 {
  return first +  " " + last; 
 }

 public static void CheckOutBook()
 {
  System.out.println("Enter book title to be check out: ");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String bookCheckOut = input.next(); 
  if(Library.BookList.contains(bookCheckOut))
  {
   Library.BookList.remove(bookCheckOut);
   System.out.println("-----" + bookCheckOut + " has been checked out!-----");
   System.out.println ("-------" + bookCheckOut + " is due in 7 days!-------");
       
  }
  else 
   System.out.println(bookCheckOut + " is not in the library. Please enter "
   + "a different book to be checked out");
  
 }
 
 public static void CheckInBook()
 {
  System.out.println("Enter book title to be checked in: ");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String bookCheckIn = input.next(); 
  if(Library.BookList.contains(bookCheckIn))
  {
   Library.BookList.add(bookCheckIn);
   System.out.println("-----" + bookCheckIn + " has been checked in!-----"); 
       
  }
  else 
   System.out.println(bookCheckIn + " is not in the library. Please enter "
   + "a different book to be checked out");
 }
 
 public boolean canBorrow()
 {
  if(bookCount <= 3)
  {
   return true; 
  } 
  else 
  {
   return false; 
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: I have some general pointers for you which ill type later when i get in front of a computer if i remember. As one note, look at your input loop. As soon as your user tries to search for a book, theyll exit.

Comment: hey thanks so much for the comment, ill keep that in mind!

Comment: Hey look i remembered.

Comment: Btw kayylai if my answer was useful, you can upvote it and if it solved the problem, you can accept it.

Comment: hey! yes thank you so much for your answer it was very useful and i appreciate the time you took to help and revise my code! sorry I'm new to this site and I'm still learning how to use it but i will definitely upvote, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This will likely involve some refactoring to your main loop.**

Alright so the way I see it, we have three classes at play here: some Patrons, which can check books out and in, some Books, which have statuses like "available" and "checked out," and a Library, which contains books. So, we need 3 classes:

I'll start with Book and use pseudo code to explain the concepts for you to implement.

```
class Book
{
    //private fields
    private final String title;
    private final String author;
    private Status available = true;
    //note--i would prefer using an Enum called status for this, 
    //but a boolean true/false value works adequately

    //Constructor
    public Book(string title, string author) {}

    //accessors for title, author, available
    //setter for available--used for Library only--there are better ways to ensure
    //Patrons can't set the status of the book, but for now this is the simplest way
}
```

As you can see, Books have immutable fields that don't need to change, and one field that tracks it status. A better implementation might make Library track book status, as that makes more logical sense and better code, but this a simple implementation.

Next, Library, which needs lots of books:

```
class Library
{
    private final ArrayList<Book> books;

    //Constructor
    public Library ()
    {
        books = loadBooks();
    }

    //some methods
    private ArrayList<Book> loadBooks () {}
    //however you want to create all your books (file input, whatever)

    public bool isBookAvailable (Book b)
    {
        if b isn't in library: return false
        else return (b in books).isAvailable()
    }

    public Book checkoutBook (Book b)
    { get book (checking availability, possibly returning a null Book), set status to unavailable, return it }

    public Book checkinBook (Book b)
    { check that this the book belongs to library, set status to available }
}
```

As I said earlier, this isn't perfect. I could spend quite some time going on and on about how to improve the design, but for the sake of simplicity won't.

Now, Patrons. One question is, should Patrons have only one library that the visit? Or do they visit multiple libraries? I'll assume they visit more than one, since sometimes a library doesn't have all the books you want.

```
class Patron
{
    private final String name;
    private final Book[] books = new Book[3];//you can see I'm limiting them to 3 books
    private int index = 0;

    //Constructor
    public Patron (String name) {}

    //methods
    public void checkoutBook (Book b, Library l)
    {//could be tricky
        check books status in l (l.isBookAvailable(b))
        if available: 
            if space (index < 2) Book newBook = l.checkoutBook(b); books[index++] = newBook;
            else: no space
        else: not available
    }

    public void checkinBook (int bookIndex, Library l)
    {
         if bookIndex < 3:
             if books[index] != null:
                 l.checkinBook (books[index]);
                 books[index--] = null;
             else: no book
         else: not valid index
    }
}
```

Of course, other utilities like displaying books (library, patron) and toString methods might be useful. But now the responsibility of the main method is to create some patrons, a library, and give patrons the chance to check out and check in books via a menu. You have the heavy lifting done; you can work on input and output now.

Any questions?

Answer (score 1):

A Beginner Level "Student Library Program" in JAVA, which interacts the Students and the Books. This Library Program can do following functions:

1-Adding a Book to Library.

2-Update Book Quantity.

3-Search a Book with its Serial number.

4-Search Books With Author Name.

5-Show all Books and their related Information.

6-Registering a Student.

7-Show All Registered Students.

8-Student can Check Out Book From Library(if registered).

:- Student can not Check Out more than 3 Books

:- You can only borrow a Book If it is Available in Library

9-Student can Check In Book to Library.

10-You can also see the Books which a Student has Checked Out(only while checking in)

```
Note: At the time it can store only 50 books for simlicity in program
```

**I Have created this program with the maximum skill and knowledge i had in java. As I'm a Beginner so I couldn't do more**

---

**Kindly give reviews about Program**

**Also tell me refinements which are to be made in program**

**Kindly Tell me the better way to do this Program**

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class book {

public int sNo;
public String bookName;
public String authorName;
public int bookQty;
public int bookQtyCopy;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public book(){

    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book:");
    this.sNo = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Book Name:");
    this.bookName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Author Name:");
    this.authorName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Quantity of Books:");
    this.bookQty = input.nextInt();
    bookQtyCopy = this.bookQty;

}

}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class books {

book theBooks[] = new book[50];     // Array that stores 'book' Objects.
public static int count;    // Counter for No of book objects Added in Array.

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




public int compareBookObjects(book b1, book b2){

    if (b1.bookName.equalsIgnoreCase(b2.bookName)){

        System.out.println("Book of this Name Already Exists.");
        return 0;

    }
    if (b1.sNo==b2.sNo){

        System.out.println("Book of this Serial No Already Exists.");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

public void addBook(book b){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (this.compareBookObjects(b, this.theBooks[i]) == 0)
            return;

    }

    if (count<50){

        theBooks[count] = b;
        count++;

    }
    else{

        System.out.println("No Space to Add More Books.");

    }

}

public void searchBySno(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSEARCH BY SERIAL NUMBER\n");

    int sNo;
    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book:");
    sNo = input.nextInt();

    int flag = 0;
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){

            System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);
            flag++;
            return;

        }

    }
    if (flag == 0)
        System.out.println("No Book for Serial No " + sNo + " Found.");

}

public void searchByAuthorName(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSEARCH BY AUTHOR'S NAME");
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Author Name:");
    String authorName = input.nextLine();
    int flag = 0;
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (authorName.equalsIgnoreCase(theBooks[i].authorName)){

            System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);
            flag++;
        }

    }
    if (flag == 0)
        System.out.println("No Books of " + authorName + " Found.");

}


public void showAllBooks(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tSHOWING ALL BOOKS\n");
    System.out.println("S.No\t\tName\t\tAuthor\t\tAvailable Qty\t\tTotal Qty");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        System.out.println(theBooks[i].sNo + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].authorName + "\t\t" + 
                theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy + "\t\t" + theBooks[i].bookQty);


    }

}

public void upgradeBookQty(){

    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tUPGRADE QUANTITY OF A BOOK\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book");
    int sNo = input.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){

            System.out.println("Enter No of Books to be Added:");
            int addingQty = input.nextInt();
            theBooks[i].bookQty += addingQty;
            theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy += addingQty;
            return;

        }

    }

}


public void dispMenu(){

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to Exit Application.");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add new Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to Upgrade Quantity of a Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to Search a Book.");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to Show All Books.");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to Register Student.");
    System.out.println("Enter 6 to Show All Registered Students.");
    System.out.println("Enter 7 to Check Out Book. ");
    System.out.println("Enter 8 to Check In Book");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------- 
   ---------------------------------------------");

}

public int isAvailable(int sNo){

    //returns the index number if available



    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (sNo == theBooks[i].sNo){
            if(theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy > 0){

                System.out.println("Book is Available.");
                return i;

            }
            System.out.println("Book is Unavailable");
            return -1;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("No Book of Serial Number " + " Available in Library.");
    return -1;


}

public book checkOutBook(){

    System.out.println("Enter Serial No of Book to be Checked Out.");
    int sNo = input.nextInt();

    int bookIndex =isAvailable(sNo);

    if (bookIndex!=-1){

        //int bookIndex = isAvailable(sNo);
        theBooks[bookIndex].bookQtyCopy--;

        return theBooks[bookIndex];
    }

    return null;

}

public void checkInBook(book b){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (b.equals(theBooks[i]) ){

            theBooks[i].bookQtyCopy++;
            return;

        }

    }

}







 }
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;    
public class student {

String studentName;
String regNum;

book borrowedBooks[] = new book[3];
public int booksCount = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public student(){

    System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
    this.studentName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Reg Number:");
    this.regNum = input.nextLine();

}
}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class students {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

student theStudents[] = new student[50];

//books book;


public static int count = 0;

public void addStudent(student s){

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if(s.regNum.equalsIgnoreCase(theStudents[i].regNum)){

            System.out.println("Student of Reg Num " + s.regNum + " is Already Registered.");
            return;
        }

    }

    if (count<=50){

        theStudents[count] = s;
        count++;

    }

}
public void showAllStudents(){

    System.out.println("Student Name\t\tReg Number");
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        System.out.println(theStudents[i].studentName + "\t\t" + theStudents[i].regNum);

    }


}

public int isStudent(){
    //return index number of student if available

     //System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
    //String studentName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Reg Number:");
    String regNum = input.nextLine();

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++){

        if (theStudents[i].regNum.equalsIgnoreCase(regNum)){

            return i;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Student is not Registered.");
    System.out.println("Get Registered First.");


    return -1;

}
public void checkOutBook(books book){
    int studentIndex =this.isStudent();

    if (studentIndex!=-1){
        System.out.println("checking out");

        book.showAllBooks();//jjjjjjjjjjjj
        book b = book.checkOutBook();
        System.out.println("checking out");
        if (b!= null){

            if (theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount<=3){
                System.out.println("adding book");
                theStudents[studentIndex].borrowedBooks[theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount] = b;
                theStudents[studentIndex].booksCount++;
                return;

            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Student Can not Borrow more than 3 Books.");
                return;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Book is not Available.");

    }

}

public void checkInBook(books book){

    int studentIndex = this.isStudent();
    if (studentIndex != -1){
        System.out.println("S.No\t\t\tBook Name\t\t\tAuthor Name");
        student s = theStudents[studentIndex];
        for (int i=0; i<s.booksCount; i++){

            System.out.println(s.borrowedBooks[i].sNo+ "\t\t\t" + s.borrowedBooks[i].bookName + "\t\t\t"+
                    s.borrowedBooks[i].authorName);

        }
        System.out.println("Enter Serial Number of Book to be Checked In:");
        int sNo = input.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<s.booksCount; i++){

            if (sNo == s.borrowedBooks[i].sNo){

                book.checkInBook(s.borrowedBooks[i]);
                s.borrowedBooks[i]=null;
                return;

            }


        }
        System.out.println("Book of Serial No "+sNo+"not Found");

    }



}


}
```

---

```
package library;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("********************Welcome to the Student Library!********************");
    System.out.println("              Please Select From The Following Options:               ");
System.out.println("**********************************************************************");
    books ob = new books();
    students obStudent = new students();
    int choice;
    int searchChoice;

    do{

        ob.dispMenu();
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch(choice){

            case 1:
                book b = new book();
                ob.addBook(b);
                break;

            case 2:
                ob.upgradeBookQty();
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to Search with Serial No.");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 to Search with Author Name(Full Name).");
                searchChoice = input.nextInt();

                switch(searchChoice){

                    case 1:
                        ob.searchBySno();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ob.searchByAuthorName();

                }
                break;

            case 4:
                ob.showAllBooks();
                break;
            case 5:
                student s = new student();
                obStudent.addStudent(s);
                break;
            case 6:
                obStudent.showAllStudents();
                break;
            case 7:
                obStudent.checkOutBook(ob);
                break;
            case 8:
                obStudent.checkInBook(ob);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("CHOICE SHOULD BE BETWEEN 0 TO 8.");

        }

    }
    while (choice!=0);
































}

}
```